# How to deserialize Claim from json in dotnet core 2.2

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core

How to deserialize a System.Security.Claims.Claim from json?

I've tried

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Claim>("my json");
```

but not working

```
JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Security.Claims.Claim. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0].Issuer', line 1, position 11.
```

Comment: Same reason why you cant do `new Claim()` no default constructor Claim()

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/Claim.cs

Comment: You need a custom `JsonConverter`.